# Open a new frame so it changes and displays a new page

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a login page, when the user clicks the login button it is supposed to display a new page (not Toplevel, and create a new window), but it doesn't seem to work.

```
root = Tk()

root.geometry('670x466')

accounts = []


class Goode_brothers:

def __init__(self, parent):

    self.myFrame = Frame(parent)
    self.myFrame.pack()


    self.load = Image.open('new-dip-project\\food.jpg')
    self.render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.load)
    self.img = Label(parent, image = self.render)
    self.img.place(x = -26, y =0)

    self.img_login = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\button (3).png')
    self.b1 = Button(parent,image = self.img_login, command = self.read_info, bd = 0, bg = '#3b353b', activebackground = '#3b353b')
    self.b1.place(x = 275, y = 340)



    self.img_register = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\register.png')
    self.b2 = Button(parent,image = self.img_register, command = self.openNewWindow, bd = 0, bg = '#3b353b', activebackground = '#3b353b')
    self.b2.place(x = 265, y = 400)

    self.canvas = Canvas(parent, width = 400, height = 120)
    self.canvas.pack()
    self.img4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('new-dip-project\\goode.png'))
    self.canvas.create_image(20, 20, anchor=NW, image=self.img4)



    self.email = Entry(parent)
    self.email.place(x = 340, y = 180)

    self.password = Entry(parent)
    self.password.place(x = 354, y = 250)

    self.img_label = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\label-image.png')
    self.name = Label(parent, image = self.img_label, text = "Email:", bg = '#3c3a3b').place(x = 197,y = 178)

    self.img_label_pass = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\label_pass.png')
    self.name = Label(parent, image = self.img_label_pass, text = "Password:", bg = '#3c3a3b').place(x = 177,y = 245)

def openMenu(self):

    self.myFrame.destroy

    self.myFrame2 = Frame()
    self.myFrame2.pack()

def read_info(self):

    with open("emails.txt") as read_ep:
        for line in read_ep:
            accounts.append(line.strip().split(", "))

    credential = [self.email.get(), self.password.get()]
    if credential in accounts:
        self.openMenu()
    else:
        self.ep_notexist = Label(root, text = "Your Email or Password is incorrect, Please try again", font=("open sans", "8"))
        self.ep_notexist.place(x = 210, y = 300)
        self.ep_notexist.after(4000, self.ep_notexist.destroy)
```

Answer (score 0):

First destroy all the widgets placed of login page by using

```
for wid in root.winfo_children():
    wid.destroy()
```

and then pack your new frame. It will work.
(if you don't want to destroy widgets you can also use `wid.pack_forget()` if you have used pack to place widgets)

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not destroy the frame in the below line:

```
def openMenu(self):

    self.myFrame.destroy   # <--- frame is not destroyed actually
```

It should be:

```
def openMenu(self):

    self.myFrame.destroy()
```

Comment: hello, thanks for you help, but i got another question, i destroyed and created a new frame, but when i try to change the background color it doesn't change, why is that?                          def openMenu(self):

        for wid in root.winfo_children():
            wid.destroy()
        self.myFrame.destroy()

        self.myFrame2 = Frame(root, bg = 'skyblue')
        self.myFrame2.pack()

        self.label24 = Label(self.myFrame2, text = 'hi')
        self.label24.pack()

Comment: First you don't need the for loop to destroy everything in the root window.  Second `myFrame2` is shrunk to the size of the label, so you cannot see its background.

Comment: but when i don't use the for loop i can still see everything that is there but when i do use the for loop the screen is white and i can see the label, and how can i make the label the size of the window and make the bg red, i am new so i am not too sure  (.geometry doesn't work)

Comment: Although you created the `myFrame`, but you put widgets into root window.  Use `myFrame2.pack(fill="both", expand=1)`.